# Magento 2 - Table report_viewed_product_index slowed down after so many page views

Tags: magento2, log, product-page

The table `report_viewed_product_index` stores the page visits of every users against their user ids.

After 1 year of user, when users have huge data of page views product detail page is slower for some users.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

## Edit

I have enabled query log on server, and observed this:

- When I open product page there are 6048 queries
- After truncating table `report_viewed_product_index` the queries on product page are just 820
- Note: In both cases, query count on `report_viewed_product_index` are just 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some test cases on data to observed behavior of slow loading.

I have figured out that when some old customers that has more browsing data is experiencing slow page load. So I have no other option but to `TRUNCATE` this table.

Here are the test cases that I have performed:

Test Case 1:

> - full records in report_viewed_product_index table
> - Customer logged in
> - Queries on product page: 6052
> - Queries on table report_viewed_product_index: 5

Test Case 1 (Repeat):

> - full records in report_viewed_product_index table
> - Customer logged in
> - Queries on product page: 6149
> - Queries on table report_viewed_product_index: 5

Test Case 2:

> - full records in report_viewed_product_index table
> - Customer not logged in
> - Queries on product page: 546
> - Queries on table report_viewed_product_index: 5

Test Case 2 (Repeat):

> - full records in report_viewed_product_index table
> - Customer not logged in
> - Queries on product page: 546
> - Queries on table report_viewed_product_index: 5

Test Case 3:

> - empty records in report_viewed_product_index table
> - Customer logged in
> - Queries on product page: 1045
> - Queries on table report_viewed_product_index: 5

Test Case 3 (Repeat):

> - empty records in report_viewed_product_index table
> - Customer logged in
> - Queries on product page: 850
> - Queries on table report_viewed_product_index: 5

Test Case 4:

> - empty records in report_viewed_product_index table
> - Customer not logged in
> - Queries on product page: 694
> - Queries on table report_viewed_product_index: 5

Test Case 4 (Repeat):

> - empty records in report_viewed_product_index table
> - Customer not logged in
> - Queries on product page: 546
> - Queries on table report_viewed_product_index: 5

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer of Shoaib Munir:

You need to truncate `report_viewed_product_index` table with this command

```
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index
```

User experience is more important than reports for management :)
So it is better to truncate this table and get view from `google analytics`